# What is the simplest way to export a Rally Query to CSV

Tags: rally

I have a number of queries that are in custom grids. I want to export the content of the custom grid to an excel sheet or a csv file but my Rally to MS Excel plugin is broken. What is the simplest to export the data?

E.g. I would like to export the results from something like this

```
((((ScheduleState < "Accepted") AND (ScheduleState > "Backlog")) AND (Owner = {user})) AND (DirectChildrenCount = 0))
```

Comment: Are you looking to find a way other than the Rally/Excel plug-in? How is it broken?

Comment: I am looking for a way other than the excel plugin. Its broken as in it some how got removed from excel and there are many layers to get through to get theses things installed. So looking for a ways without installing anything.

Comment: The alternate would be to copy the contents of the custom grid into a spread sheet or email so I could share it with people outside of rally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think the easiest way may be to create a custom view.

1. So, Plan tab, select user stories
2. Below the tabs you will see a "views" drop down list.
3. Just to the right of that is an icon with a + on it.
4. Set up the content you want to include (columns etc)
5. There is no query you can enter so far as I am aware but you can use the column filters in Rally
6. Once filtered click on actions and export to the file type of your choice.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Not exactly what i was looking for but i just wanted to confirm my understanding.